# php md5 Questions?

Tags: php, md5, unique

I have two simple questions:

1. Is md5 hexadecimal or alphanumeric?
2. Can I change every words with number but keep uniqueness of md5?

Comment: Both your questions are difficult to understand. Please clarify them, they don't really make sense. At the same time, MD5 hashes are _not_ unique at all. It is a hash function...

Comment: Since MD5 is a Hashing algorithm there is no guarantee that md5("string") is not equal to md5("other String"). So the answer to the second question is actually no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. An MD5 hash is typically expressed as a hexadecimal number, 32
   digits long. And that's exactly what PHP gives you. Here is an
   example:

   `AB654FEC7EC9054CD3289FAFBF4356FC`
2. Obviously, an MD5 hash is not unique. But it is very hard to find
   collisions, and chances are you won't. This kind of algorithm is
   specifically designed to produce dramatic changes in response to
   small modifications.

**Additional resources:**

- You can find more informations about MD5 hashes on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).
- Here is an article about [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistant), to give you a bigger picture for your question #2.
- You may also want to take a look at the [php manual page](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.md5.php) for md5().

Answer (score 3):

1.

> Returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number.

From [PHP](http://php.net/md5)

2 With reasonable probability, yes. But we are talking about a hashing algorithm, so you need to  [understand MD5 collisions](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/).

Answer (score 2):

answer:

1.hexadecimal
2.yes, you can